# Bind dataset with reflection give the message "object must be Iconvertible"

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the next two methods, works to implement bind the results of multiple store proeceadures into models, my codes:

```
public static List<T> SPReader<T>(string procedure, TokenSessionSeus tokenSesion, params object[] parameteres) where T : new()
        {
            var model = new List<T>();
            var type = typeof(T);
            var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            var conection = OpenConnection(procedure, tokenSesion, parameteres);

            DataAccess consultar = new DataAccess();
            DataSet ds = consultar.GetData(conection);
            var consulta = new DataSources<ModelosEquivalentes>();

            #region
            var t = typeof(T);
            var fieldValues = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var tableModel = new List<TableModel>();

            foreach (var field in fieldValues)
            {
                var attr = (MetaAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetaAttribute), false);
                if (!attr.Any())
                    break;

                var typesToCast = (field.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                    ? field.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name
                    : field.PropertyType.Name;

                tableModel.Add(new TableModel
                {
                    ModelName = field.Name,
                    ModelType = typesToCast
                });
            }
            #endregion

            for (var i = 0; i <= tableModel.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                Type currentType = Type.GetType("ApiCRMDrive.Models." + tableModel[i].ModelType);
                MethodInfo method = typeof(GestionVendedor).GetMethod("ToModel");
                MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(currentType);

                var result = generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { ds.Tables[0] });
                object o = Activator.CreateInstance(currentType);

                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = Type.GetType("ApiCRMDrive.Models." + type.Name).GetProperty(tableModel[i].ModelName);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(o, Convert.ChangeType(result, currentType), null);
            }

            //var result = ToModel<EmpresasInfoModel>(ds.Tables[1]);
            return model;
        }

        public static List<T> ToModel<T>(this DataTable dt)
        {
            List<string> columns = (from DataColumn dc in dt.Columns select dc.ColumnName).ToList();

            var fields = typeof(T).GetFields();
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            List<T> lst = new List<T>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                var ob = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                foreach (var fieldInfo in fields.Where(fieldInfo => columns.Contains(fieldInfo.Name)))
                {
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(ob, !dr.IsNull(fieldInfo.Name) ? dr[fieldInfo.Name] : fieldInfo.FieldType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(fieldInfo.FieldType) : null);
                }

                foreach (var propertyInfo in properties.Where(propertyInfo => columns.Contains(propertyInfo.Name)))
                {
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(ob, !dr.IsNull(propertyInfo.Name) ? dr[propertyInfo.Name] : propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType) : null);
                }

                lst.Add(ob);
            }

            return lst;
        }
```

Ok, whats the problem then?

At the moment to assign a value to the property with:

```
Type currentType = Type.GetType("ApiCRMDrive.Models." + tableModel[i].ModelType);
                MethodInfo method = typeof(GestionVendedor).GetMethod("ToModel");
                MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(currentType);

                var result = generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { ds.Tables[0] });
                object o = Activator.CreateInstance(currentType);

                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = Type.GetType("ApiCRMDrive.Models." + type.Name).GetProperty(tableModel[i].ModelName);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(o, Convert.ChangeType(result, currentType), null); //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
```

For some reason, in the last line (`Convert.ChangeType`) to assign the result, I get the error:

> Object must implement Iconvertible

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we can copy and pasted into a console app to repro the issue.

Comment: It's the second part of the code, that is the extract, of the biggest code @mjwills